# Spring Boot JMS client

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I have used couple of days trying to find simple example of how to implement a JMS client with minimum possible number of dependencies.

In internet you can find tons of examples. But Spring Boot examples exclusively use local broker. Most of them have ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ starter dependency & nothing else.

I can see that this is a kind of "general question" that Stack Overflow doesn't like, but I can not figure out were to go. No help from Spring docs either.

And I am sure there not very many lines of code are needed if you just know what to do!

EDIT: I just want a JMS listener.

Comment: Why not just change the Spring Boot examples to use a non-local broker?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me...Are you looking to implement a JMS client *with Spring Boot* with the fewest dependencies or just a JMS client with the fewest dependencies? Also, when you say "JMS listener" are you talking about a plain JMS `MessageListener` or a Spring `JmsListener`?

Comment: I am just looking for a simple example application with simpliest possible jms client . Example that has all the configuration that is needed , like host:port, credentials, queue name ... what ever is needed. 
Though somehow I thought that Spring Boot would have something like "spring-boot-jms-client-starter" that would have made things most easy (just add configuration into application.properties).
I don't know about differencies between jms-client and messaging-client, probably wolud not make any difference to be, to get started.